# Linking two elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

Is there a possibility of "linking" two CSS elements in jQuery?

An example from my project:
I'd like to append a `.focused` class to multiple elements at once when certain things happen. They all have the same prefix in their ID, but there is >1 of those prefixes (like `#first-header` - `#first-button` ; `#second-header` - `#second-button` and so on). It would probably use some regular expressions, but I can't seem to figure this stuff out.

A more accurate example, because I'm bad at explaining things:
When `#first-header` is `.focused`, append the same `.focused` class to `#first-button` as well. And that would need to work to any pair of **-header** and **-button**.

I hope I explained it well enough and am thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: This is what classes are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('[id$="header"]').on('focus blur', function(e) {
    $('#' + this.id.split('-').shift() + '-button').toggleClass('focused', e.type=='focus');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqF66/)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily select all items whose id starts with `first-` like this

```
$('[id^="first-"]').addClass('whatever');
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like instead of using patterns in the ID of your HTML elements you should be using classes.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="first-button" class="button">...</div>
<div id="second-button" class="button">///</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".button").click(function(){ /*do stuff*/});
```

That Javascript would attach a click handler to all div elements with the class `button`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple ids for one element.  The proper way to do what you're doing is to give everything that you want to change a class like "toFocus"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("[name$='header']").focus(function(){
    var t = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[0];
    $("#"+t+"-button").addClass("focus");
});
```